# Merge few lines into one

Tags: reactjs

I have a media player with markup. Currently, the markup looks like this

[image]

Here are some useful parts of code:

```
return data.map((item, i) => {
      // console.log('item: ',item);
      let display = 'block';

      let left = null;
      let position = (item.position / 1000) * ratio;
      // console.log(position);
      // check if low duration or position of point is bigger than duration of media
      if (duration >= 1) {
        if (position <= 100) {
          left = position  + '%';
        } else {
          // if outside if bar then hide element
          display = 'none';
        }
      } else {
        display = 'none';
      }



let styleLine = {
        display: display,
        // position: 'absolute',
        width: left,
        height: '3px',
        paddingLeft: left,
        backgroundColor: item.lineColor,
      }
      //create style for point
      let stylePoint = {
        height: '9px',
        width: '9px',
        backgroundColor: item.color,
        display: display,
        position: 'absolute',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        borderRadius: '25px',
        marginTop: '-2px',
        marginLeft: '-2px',
        //zIndex: '15',
        left: left,
      };

      return (
        // <span key={i} style={stylePoint} onClick={this.handleClick}></span>
        <span key={i} >
          <span style={styleLine}></span>
          <span style={stylePoint} onClick={this.handleClick}></span>
        </span>
      )
    })
  };
```

What I need is one colorful line that starts with the first color till the red point then proceeds with the second one, not two separate lines with the same beginning.
I've tryied to play with z-index but that didn't work. What could be the right solution?

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible to create different lines for each color and set their position as absolute? So when one to finish you start another from that point using css left attribute.

Comment: It didn't work properly, cause the first line should start from the very beginning.

Comment: This answer should probably be a comment